# Docusign - date tab - formatting input

Tags: docusignapi

I am having difficulty specifying the format of the date tab to be inputted as dd/mm/yyyy.  This is a date input tab, it is NOT the date signed tab.

I HAVE changed the account default regional settings to my time zone and changed the default date/time format for the account under regional settings.  However, this appears to have no impact on the users input for the date tab upon signing.

I am using REST-api to send the tags, so please don't provide advice based on using a template!  It has to be either in the account settings (of which there doesn't appear to be) or in the specification of the date tab in the code (I'm using c#).

[click here to see example use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I62P5.png)

```
public static List<Date> CreateDateTabs(IEnumerable<Docusign_Date> DD)
    {
        List<Date> listTabs = new List<Date>();
        foreach (Docusign_Date item in DD)
        {
            Date DS = new Date();
            DS.DocumentId = item.DocumentGuid.ToString();
            DS.RecipientId = item.PartyID.ToString();
            DS.TabLabel = item.Party_Tag;
            DS.AnchorString = item.Party_Tag;
            listTabs.Add(DS);
        }
        return listTabs;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example shows a text tab, not a date tab.
I know it's confusing.
But in DocuSign if you want user to provide input date, you must use a text tab and set it such that the required format is for date.
Change your code to textTab, add formatting based on your requirement (first day (1-31), then month (1-12), then year) and you can even provide the error message if someone provides the wrong date.
Let me know if it's not clear and you need a code example.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I'm a bit confused.  Firstly I presume in your first sentence you mean my example shows a date tab, not a text tab, as you then go onto say I should use a text tab.

But either way I'm confused.  Why does docusign provide a date tab but then require you to use a text tab formatted as a date, if I understand you correctly.  I notice a lot of their fields aren't strongly typed and instead use strings everywhere, which is incredibly annoying!

Some sample code would be awesome.  Thank you so much :)